# Tortoise SVN - merging changes to Trunk from Branch without update

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

My trunk is having lot of changes which are committed by other developers. I am working on a branch which is derived from Trunk here I don't want trunk changes but Trunk needs my changes. Can I directly merge my branch changes to Trunk without merging Trunk to branch ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible. You can merge your branch in trunk.